# skill -KILL -u $user Command on Max OS X?

Tags: macos, script, command-line

Is there an alternative for the `skill -KILL -u $user` command on the Mac OSx. The basic requirement is I want to log out my current logged in user at end of shell script

This program logs out Linux log in user .

Comment: Do you want to log out/exit from the shell you are running in or log out the user from Finder?

Answer (score 1):

From the man page of `skill`

> These tools are obsolete and unportable.  The command syntax is poorly defined. Consider using the killall, pkill, and pgrep commands instead.

so you could use `pkill -KILL -u uid`.

But why kill every process with the KILL signal? You can just call `exit` after your script:

```
script.sh ; exit
```

Comment: I think you left a `k` out of `pkill`

Comment: The above command is not working in OS X 10.9 :(

Comment: @prateeakojha the pkill command? Do you get an error message? What are you exactly doing?